# Solve the system of functional equations.

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
\begin{cases}
f(x(1+f(x)))=f(x)^2,\\
f(x(1-f(x)))=f(x) f(-x),\\
f(x(-1+f(-x)))=f(x)f(-x).
\end{cases}

I have found only that for nontrivial $f$  must be $f(0)=1$ and have  no more ideas.

Comment: You can omit the third equation as it's obtained by replacing $-x$ for $x$ in the second equation.

Comment: $f(x)=0$, $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x+1$ are solutions to the equation.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=ax+1$ are the only polynomial solutions to the equation.

Comment: Might be both late and not much help, but $f : x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 \,\,\text{if}\,\, x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 0 \,\,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ can be shown to also be a solution, so getting a satisfying form of the solutions might be tricky?

Comment: It seems there are actually a lot of non-continuous solutions: if we let $$\begin{cases}\mathcal{A} := \{A \subset \mathbb{R} \mid (0 \in A) \,\,\underline{\text{and}}\,\, (x \in A \Rightarrow -x \in A \,\,\underline{\text{and}}\,\, 2x \in A)\} \\ \mathcal{B} := \{A \subset \mathbb{R} \mid (0 \not\in A) \,\,\underline{\text{and}}\,\, (x \in A \Rightarrow -x \not\in A \,\,\underline{\text{and}}\,\, 2x \in A)\}\end{cases}$$ then the $f := _A$ for $A \in \mathcal{A} \sqcup \mathcal{B}$ are exactly the solutions $f$ such that $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \{0,1\}$.